# Heroku + Carrierwave: images not found after deploy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I upload images with Carrierwave to Heroku (`/public/uploads`).

The problem is uploaded images are disappearing after every deploy to Heroku. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku does not store images for a longer time.

```
You can store images separately using Amazon S3.
```

Visit - 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3